# Script para Copiar diretório para pasta Program Files com direitos de Administrador

Tags: script, batch, active-directory

Boa tarde pessoal,
Gostaria de copiar alguns arquivos em *.vbs, para uma pasta em "*Program Files(X86)*" via logon Script. Porém a mensagem que aparece é que o usuário não possui direitos para efetuar a cópia.

```
psexec.exe -d -nobanner -u DOMÍNIO\administrator -p "SENHA" "copy \\meu servidor\pasta pública\arquivos  %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\OCINV~1\Plugins%"
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: o psexec.exe será barrado por parte (todos?) os antivirus...

Answer (score 0):

> **Update:** Baseado no comentário, desabilite **`UAC (User-Account-Control)`**...

Na estação/servidor/pc onde executar o psexec.exe:

Se dando um **`reg query`** na chave abaixo retornar: **`EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1`**

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" | findstr "EnableLUA"
Rem :: EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1

rem ::  Então adicione a entrada/valor 0
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

---

**1)** Sugiro verificar na estação de destino, se existe essa chave e se está habilitada(0x1):

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system" | find "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" | find "0x1"
```

Se ela existir e estiver habilitada, o comando lhe retorna:

```bat
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

**2)** Se acaso não existir ou o valor difere de 0x1, use esse comando para adicionar/habilitar:

```bat
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system" /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

**3)** Remova o argumento -d e adicione -i -h -s, use senha sem aspas e tente com cmd /c copy:

```bat
psexec.exe -i -h -s -nobanner -u dominio\administrator -p SENHA "cmd /c copy "\\meu servidor\pasta publica\arquivos\*.vbs"  "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\OCINV~1\Plugins\""
```

**4)** [Consulte a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec):

**Obs.: 1)** Opção 1 e 2 são para possibilitar acesso remoto.

**Obs.: 2)** Busquei publicações online sobre o tema sem encontrar nada que afirme que a cópia de arquivos via ação remota, possa operar em pastas de destino que não seja entre pastas compartilhadas, há apenas algumas pouca que sugerem a criação de um bat para esse tarefa.

**Obs.: 3)** Código não foi testado.

---

Comment: Testei seu código @It Wasn't Me, e apareceu a seguinte mensagem: Couldn't install PSEXESVC service:

Comment: Está com a mesma mensagem **Couldn't install PSEXESVC service:**

Comment: Foi editada tem algumas horas...